# Explaining the 6th fetter?

Tags: rebirth, fetters

What is exactly meant by "Material rebirth lust", and how is it properly abandoned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pali is rūparāgo. 'Rūpa' means 'materiality' and 'rāgo' means 'lust'.

It is lust for rupa jhana, i.e., 1st, 2nd, 3rd &/or 4th jhana.

It is not lust for 'rebirth'. The word 'rebirth' is not found in the Pali.

It is abandoned by the destruction of lust & clinging, i.e., Nibbana.

It is abandoned as follows:

> Take a mendicant who, quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded
>   from unskillful qualities, enters and remains in the first absorption.
>   They contemplate the phenomena there—included in form, feeling,
>   perception, choices, and consciousness—as impermanent, as suffering (unsatisfactory),
>   as diseased, as an abscess, as a dart, as misery, as an affliction, as
>   alien, as falling apart, as empty, as not-self. They turn their mind
>   away from those things, and apply it to the deathless: ‘This is
>   peaceful; this is sublime—that is, the stilling of all activities, the
>   letting go of all attachments, the ending of craving, fading away,
>   cessation, extinguishment (Nibbana).’ Abiding in that they attain the ending of
>   defilements.
>
> [AN 9.36](https://suttacentral.net/an9.36/en/sujato)

Answer (score 2):

The 6th fetter's meaning pretty straightforward: the craving for the fine-material (or form) existence/Rupa-Raga. The lower 5 fetters are lower because they're all related to our world, which is the sensuous world (Kama-Loka), while the 5 higher fetters are those that are tie to the 2 higher worlds above Kama-Loka: Rupa-Loka (form or fine-material world), and Arupa-Loka (or immaterial world) (see [Planes of Existence](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html) and [RupaRaga](https://suttacentral.net/define/r%C5%ABpar%C4%81ga) for further details).